# Scope of variables inside functions

Tags: common-lisp, literals

I have written a function that returns a prime factorization of numbers n less than 20. The function uses a let to create a list of exponents, and increments those exponents when it finds that n is divisible by a prime.

In my Lisp interpreter (both gcl and clisp), when I call the following function once, I get the correct factorization but when I call it a second time, I get the sum of the factorizations of the first and second function - but isn't the scope of `exponents` limited to the inside of the let!? Why isn't `exponents` being re-assigned the value `'(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)`? How can I re-write this function so that it will withstand multiple calls?

```
(setf primes '(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19))

(defun factorize (n)
  (let ((exponents '(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)))
    (loop for i from 0 to (- (length primes) 1) do
          (loop while (and (= (mod n (nth i primes)) 0) 
                           (not (= n 1))) do
            (incf (nth i exponents))
            (setf n (/ n (nth i primes)))))
    (return-from factorize exponents)))
```

Output:

```
>(factorize 10) ;; first time
(1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0) ;; 2^1*5*1 = 10, correct
>(factorize 10)
(2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0) ;; wrong
>(factorize 10)
(3 0 3 0 0 0 0 0)
```

Comment: Quoted data is literal data.  If you're familiar with C, you might recognize the behavior from literal character arrays in the code. The *reader* creates a literal list of zeros for you, and that list is stored in the compiled code, so you have only one list, and it's shared between all runs of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list '(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0) is stored as a literal, and modifying a literal is undefined behaviour. You should use

```
(let ((exponents (copy-list '(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0))))
```

to make a copy of the literal every time you need it, or alternatively

```
 (let ((exponents (list 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)))
```

Btw, use

```
(defparameter *primes* '(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19))
```

rather than `setf` at the top level. Note the `*` signs which are a convention to indicate that this is a special variable.

Comment: Even better, since the length of exponents should be the same as the number of primes `(mapcar (constantly 0) *primes*)`.

Comment: And don't use `return-from` here.

Comment: Yes, the loop construct `finally (return exponents)` would be clearer.  Along with that, the exponents list could be `(loop with exponents = ...`, too.

Answer (score 2):

Just another fun loop-based solution that doesn't involve random access into lists (which is rather inefficient).  This also makes use of [**truncate**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_floorc.htm#truncate), which returns a quotient and a remainder as multiple values (which you can collect with [**multiple-value-list**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_mult_1.htm) and destructure with **loop**.  Since you can iterate through the primes, you can just collect the exponents as you do so:

```
(defparameter *primes* '(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19))

(defun factorize (n)
  (loop
     for p in *primes* 
     collect (loop
                for (quotient remainder) = (multiple-value-list (truncate n p))
                while (zerop remainder)
                count (setf n quotient))))
```

```
CL-USER> (factorize 10)
(1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0)
CL-USER> (factorize 12)
(2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0)
CL-USER> (factorize (* 19 19 11 5 7 2 2))
(2 0 1 1 1 0 0 2)
```

Of course, once you're iterating through a list and collecting a value for each other value, you could just use mapcar.